# Resizing a tablelist

Tags: widget, tcl, dynamic, resize, tk-toolkit

Can I resize a tablelist without recreate the widget?

I have two tablelist widgets (each into a grid).
One is always displayed, the other is hidden until you press a button.
When the second tablelist is displayed as well, I want resize the first one to half the number of rows (for reasons of screen's readability).
Then, if you close the second tablelist, I would come back the first to its original height (initial number of rows).
How can I achieve this?.
(NOTE:the question is mainly about if is possible resize a nemethi's tablelist in dynamic way.)

Answer (score 2):

All Tk widgets have a size that they'd prefer to be, but can cope with less than that. So we need to take advantage of this.

You've got a container (a toplevel or possibly a frame) that will contain the two tablelist widgets (or just one of them when only one is meant to be displayed). When the second tablelist is added, we want to keep the size of the overall container the same. The simplest method of doing this is with the `place` geometry manager — in this case, especially its relative placement and sizing controls — since that lets you control widget sizing more precisely. (The down-side is that you *have* to do some work yourself to get initial widget sizes right.)

In the code below, I'm assuming that the container widget is called `.container`, the main widget is called `.container.main` and the extra is called `.container.extra`. To set things up:

```
place .container.main
bind .container.main <Configure> {initMainSize %W %w %h}
proc initMainSize {widget width height} {
    # Set up the container preferred size
    [winfo parent $widget] configure -width $width -height $height
    # Install the real placement rules for the main widget
    place configure $widget -relx 0 -rely 0 -relwidth 1 -relheight 1
    # Run this only once, so remove the binding here
    bind $widget <Configure> {}
}
```

How to add `.container.extra`:

```
# Extra widget to take bottom half of container; main relegated to top half
place .container.extra -relx 0 -rely 0.5 -relheight 0.5 -relwidth 1
place configure .container.main -relheight 0.5
```

How to remove `.container.extra`:

```
# Extra widget dropped (but still logically exists); main back to full size
place forget .container.extra
place configure .container.main -relheight 1
```

Also note that because of the general increased trickiness of using `place`, you're better off using it for as few widgets as possible; use it on a frame that you then `pack`/`grid` into the rest of your GUI (your button for togggling display of the second tablelist, etc.)

Comment: Before anyone asks, this can't be done with `pack` on its own as that has the wrong strategy for handling widget shrinking, and while `grid` can do it with the right constraints, it doesn't like it at all (I tried, and as soon as I removed the constraint I'd set with `wm maxsize` everything changed size again; this might be platform-dependent behavior but its unwanted). The relatively-rare `place` GM is exactly right for this task, but needs that `<Configure>` binding.